# Tomcat, service unavailable 503

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tomcat, google-visualization

My webapp uses JSP / JavaScript/ google visualization, and runs on Tomcat 7 on a 64bit windows server with enough resources dedicated to this app.It is still under testing, so, I have control over the load.

The problem is when I work from device at same network of the server, everything works fine. But when I work from device from different network with a request took a long time (more than 6 minutes) I get Service Unavailable [503] message after 6 minutes of waiting while processing in the server is going on and completed successfully. I checked the Tomcat logs but i couldn't find any thing every thing seems to be work fine. I tried different solutions but non of them worked with me:

- Increase Tomcat's connector timeout.
- Increase the Tomcat RAM.
- Disable the server firewall
- Try different browsers
- Adjust the request timeout from the browser.

I experimented by setting Tomcat's Connector properties in conf/server.xml. I played around with all combinations and ranges of connectionTimeout and keepAliveTimeout.

The final configuration is:

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
          address="0.0.0.0"
          connectionTimeout="3600000"
          redirectPort="8443" />
```

I'm wondering if anybody else has run into such a problem, and how they solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you server.xml is having wrong data . Change connector port from 80 to 8080 it always allow four digit and start from 8080 not sure . please update as below

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
      address="0.0.0.0"
      connectionTimeout="3600000"
      redirectPort="8443" />
```

**503 Service Unavailable**

The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a
      server must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish
      to simply refuse the connection.[click here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4) for more information 
let me know if you face any issue